# Capture Keys.Down and Keys.Up on dataGridview_KeyDown

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a `DataGridView` where each of its rows' indexes correspond to an index in a `List<SomeClass>`, e.g. second row of the `DataGridView` corresponds to `List[1]` (counting from zero), etc. When the user clicks on column 0 of dataGridView1, I display `List[e.RowIndex]` on another `DataGridView` like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && !dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Data[e.RowIndex].Values.Count; j++)
            {
                //add Data[e.RowIndex].Values to dataGridView2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine and I am trying to implement the same thing but this time using the up and down keys of the keyboard using the KeyDown event:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)            
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex - 1].IsNewRow)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            e.Handled = true;
        }                
        if (!dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].IsNewRow) 
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < Data[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Values.Count; j++)
            {
                //add Data[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Values to dataGridView2
            }
        }
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < Data[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex - 1].Values.Count; j++)
            {
                //add Data[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex - 1].Values to dataGridView2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works but produces an

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

error, in the 2nd `if`, on the following two cases:

- When using the up arrow until row 0 and once there the down arrow
- When scrolling to row * (the new row always located at the bottom of the dataGridView).

I seem to be missing out something here, could anyone help me or point me to the right direction?

Comment: is this for sliverlight? wpf? windows forms? asp.net? (etc) the solution is different depending on which one you are using

Comment: hi, this is on windows forms. i will update that in my original post.

Comment: @trashr0x - Please use the tags.

Comment: Overriding keyboard handling in DGV is very troublesome.  Use the RowEnter event instead.

Comment: @HansPassant this worked like a charm, simple and without any trouble whatsoever. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue too and in case there is anyone out there like me, who typically ignores comments and only looks for answers, Hans Passant's comment

"Overriding keyboard handling in DGV is very troublesome. Use the RowEnter event instead. – Hans Passant Feb 15 '12 at 2:47"

is one correct solution.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer to confirm that indeed Hans Passant's comment was the actual answer